# Load a JPEG as binary in a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rsa, signing

my goal is to sign a JPEG-File with jsrasign: https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign

There is a demo to sign a normal String: https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/sample/sample-rsasign.html

How can I use this demo to adopt this for a JPEG files? I could not find a way to save the complete untouched binary of an JPEG file in a variable.

But I need this since verification will fail if the binary of the image is changed or different.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Beispiel Applikation für Signaturen per JS</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/jsrsasign-all-min.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function doSign() {
  var sigpw = document.form1.pwsig.value;
  var rsa = new RSAKey();
  var decryptedKeyHex = KEYUTIL.getDecryptedKeyHex(document.form1.prvkey1.value, sigpw);
  rsa.readPKCS5PrvKeyHex(decryptedKeyHex);
  var hashAlg = document.form1.hashalg.value;
  var hSig = rsa.sign(document.form1.msgsigned.value, hashAlg);
  document.form1.siggenerated.value = linebrk(hSig, 64);
}

function doVerify() {
  var sMsg = document.form1.msgverified.value;
  var hSig = document.form1.sigverified.value;

  var pubKey = KEYUTIL.getKey(document.form1.cert.value);
  var isValid = pubKey.verify(sMsg, hSig);

  // display verification result
  if (isValid) {
    _displayStatus("valide");
  } else {
    _displayStatus("invalide");
  }
}

function copyMsgAndSig() {
  _displayStatus("reset");
  document.form1.msgverified.value = document.form1.msgsigned.value; 
  document.form1.sigverified.value = document.form1.siggenerated.value; 
}

function _displayStatus(sStatus) {
  var div1 = document.getElementById("verifyresult");
  if (sStatus == "valide") {
    div1.style.backgroundColor = "skyblue";
    div1.innerHTML = "Die Signatur ist *VALIDE*.";
  } else if (sStatus == "invalide") {
    div1.style.backgroundColor = "deeppink";
    div1.innerHTML = "Die Signatur ist *NICHT VALIDE*.";
  } else {
    div1.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    div1.innerHTML = "Bitte Felder ausfüllen und Jetzt signieren klicken.";
  }
}

</script>
<style type="text/css">
TD  {vertical-align: top}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Beispiel Applikation für Signaturen per JS</h1>

<form name="form1">
<table border="0">
<tr><th>Signieren</th><th></th><th>Verifizieren</th></tr>

<tr>
<td>
PEM RSA Privater Schüssel<br/>
<!-- _test/z5.* for X.509v1 certificate and private key -->
<textarea name="prvkey1" rows="10" cols="65">
Hier deinen privaten Schlüssel einfügen.
</textarea><br/>
Welcher Text soll signiert werden?.<br/>
<input type="text" name="msgsigned" value="Dein Text"/><br/>
Bitte Passwort eingeben:<br/>
<input type="text" name="pwsig" size="20"/><br/>
</td>
<td></td>
<td>
Ergebnisse der Verifikation
<div id="verifyresult" style="background: yellow">Bitte Felder ausfüllen und auf Jetzt signieren klicken</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<select name="hashalg">
<option value="sha1" selected>SHA1
<option value="sha256">SHA256
<option value="sha512">SHA512
<option value="md5">MD5
<option value="ripemd160">RIPEMD-160
</select>
<input type="button" value="Jetzt signieren" onClick="doSign();"/><br/>
</td>
<td>
<input type="button" value="Kopieren" onClick="copyMsgAndSig();"/><br/>
</td>
<td>
<input type="button" value="Signatur verifizieren" onClick="doVerify();"/><br/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
Generierte Signatur<br/>
<textarea name="siggenerated" rows="4" cols="65"></textarea>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
Signatur verifizieren<br/>
<textarea name="sigverified" rows="4" cols="65">
Hier steht bald deine Signatur
</textarea><br/>
Welcher Text soll verifiziert werden?<br/>
<input type="text" name="msgverified" value="Dein Text"/><br/>
Öffentlicher Schlüssel des Urhebers.<br/>
<textarea name="cert" rows="10" cols="65">
Hier deinen öffentlichen Schlüssel einfügen.
</textarea><br/>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Instead of getting the value of input text

```
document.form1.msgsigned.value
```

I would like to inject a JPEG in variable here

```
var hSig = rsa.sign(variableWithJPEGinIt, hashAlg);
```

The picture will be taken by a user on his smartphone. If this will not work with JS only I can also use Cordova or other options, but would be great to do this in   normal JS.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code.

Comment: If you're using node.js then you want [the fs module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) and you can load the file into [a Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

Comment: Uploaded the code, not using Node.JS.

Comment: What image file? One residing on your server that you simply specify the path to somewhere, one the user uploads from the client, …?

Comment: A picture which was taken by the user locally on a smartphone. I can use Cordova if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need an INPUT of type `file` and `accept="image/*;capture=camera"` (the latter is optional but will immediately open the camera instead of asking to choose a file first). Listen for the `change` event on this INPUT and then use the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read the file - either as binary or as DataURI.